# Spark MLlib predict only if threshold greater than value

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have a multi class classification (38 classes) problem and implemented a pipeline in Spark ML in order to solve it. This is how I generated my model.

```
val nb = new NaiveBayes()
  .setLabelCol("id")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
  .setThresholds(Seq(1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25,1.25).toArray)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(stages, assembler, nb))

val model = pipeline.fit(trainingSet)
```

I want my model to be able to predict a class only if it's confidence (probability) is greater than 0.8%.

I searched a lot in Spark documentation to understand better what the threshold parameter means, but the only relevant piece of information i've found is this one:

> Thresholds in multi-class classification to adjust the probability of
>   predicting each class. Array must have length equal to the number of
>   classes, with values > 0 excepting that at most one value may be 0.
>   The class with largest value p/t is predicted, where p is the original
>   probability of that class and t is the class's threshold.

This is why my thresholds are 1.25.

The problem is that no matter the value I'm inserting for the thresholds, it seams it doesn't affect my predictions at all.

Do you know if there is a possibility to predict only classes that have the confidence (probability) greater than a specific threshold?

Another way would be to select only the predictions that have the probability greater than that threshold, but I expect this can be achieved using the framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect any change if you set the same value for each class?

Comment: Well, given that the documentation does not explain in depth the concept of threshold, I expect that for each class to predict only values with probability greater than 0.8%, if the probability is lower, I don't want to predict that value